# Problems with Women Making Kiddush in Public?

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, kol-isha

I read in Shulchan Aruch that a woman can make kiddush for a man, but it seems to me that there's a kol isha issue with doing so publicly, i.e. at a table at a shul or large gathering. Are there any sources that perhaps rule otherwise?

Comment: The seridei esh has a teshuva about zemirot on shabbat and other דברים שבקדושה where kol isha is not necessarily an issue

Comment: Is there a kol ishah issue when she talks at the table the rest of the meal?

Comment: *Tavo me'era* would be the bigger issue, I figure.

Answer (score 0):

Yalkut Yosef siman 271 doesn't mention Kol Isha, just that it would be immodest if it's not her immediate family. He says furthermore that it is immodest if she is reciting it *for a man*. How this translates into practical situations is very context-dependant and should be decided with the aid of one's LOR.

Comment: Dozens of rishonim also don't mention kol isha https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45064/759

Comment: As with most issues of modesty, context is everything. Unless he is positing a formal prohibition (which I don't think anyone does here) this is entirely context dependant

Comment: @DoubleAA indeed, he has written, like many do, "immodesty" into halacha, yet is very vague about it and therefore one should consult one's LOR for context dependent situations

Comment: I believe Ovadia Yosef rules that women publicly reading prayers and reading from scripture are not automatically qol isha. Secular songs are qol isha